# Should programs terminate on ENOSPC error?

Tags: bash, busybox, hexdump, od

In bash, the command `hexdump -C /dev/urandom > hexdump.txt` does not terminate.

It keeps going indefinitely, even if the filesystem is full.

```
read(0, "\326\210L0\rL<\177\207\214\3\2237\vi\315\232P\303\275\345\26jDy\272\262\233\304\340g\7"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, " ac 78 78 bf 6e 54 de 64  c8 89 "..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "[|\n012f40d0  1c 14 ea 0b 12 8a 9"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "M......Uo/9i1|\n012f4410  2c f8 3"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, " 1a 7c  |{...wSZq5/.{...||\n012f4"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "25 fa d5 67 7a 93  |.=...j}V>.%."..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
read(0, "\336&v\266I\10\254\3551\225\370\"^g\224\10\5\17h\tNkA.(\374\302\333`K/\332"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, " ad  7a 3f 0c f4 0e a0 b8 8d  |."..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "ab 1c f4 79 f1  49 20 0e a1 f3 7"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
```

In the event that it does terminate (when the input is not infinite) it still reports a write error at the very end... but by that point it has consumed the input entirely, producing countless ENOSPC errors.

Then I tested other commands. `busybox hexdump` has the same issue. `od` has the same issue. `strings` has the same issue...

So this involves util-linux, coreutils, binutils, ...?

I can work around the issue like `hexdump -C /dev/urandom | cat > hexdump.txt` this works since `cat`, `dd`, `pv` terminates on write error, which in turn kills the entire pipe. But it looks so weird.

Is this a bug across the board or is there some standard that requires these utils must consume all inputs?

Comment: The `write(2)` system call will return an error if the write fails but I am not aware of any standard that asks for it to abort the job. I would consider this to be bad programming practice in general but not a bug.

Comment: Reported it and seems like it will be fixed!

https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/2205#issuecomment-1523578612